# Python user input for def function

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

How to do a number input by user first then only display the answer?

```
a = int(raw_input("Enter number: "),twoscomp)

def tobin(x, count = 8):
    return "".join(map(lambda y:str((x>>y)&1), range(count-1, -1, -1)))

def twoscomp(bin_str):
    return tobin(-int(bin_str,2),len(bin_str))

print a
```

Comment: You can define your function first and call it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do?

```
def tobin(x, count = 8):
    return "".join(map(lambda y:str((x>>y)&1), range(count-1, -1, -1)))

def twoscomp(bin_str):
    return tobin(-int(bin_str,2),len(bin_str))

a = twoscomp(raw_input("Enter number: "))

print a
```

Things to note:

- You need to define things before you use them, and that includes functions.
- Indentation is important, and you should use it.